# fprintf is not working as expected in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, formatting, format, printf

I have the below code in MATLAB. I use version R2019a.

```
clc;
clear all;
K = 100;
r = 5:1:55;
W = 10;
t = round((2*K.*r.^2+W^2)./60);
%disp("Turn : " + r + " " + t);
str = "Turn : ";
fprintf("%s %d %d",str,r,t)
```

I want to use `fprintf` instead of `disp`. `r` and `t` are  1x51 double variables.

[image: screen shot of Workspace variable list]

When I use `fprintf` without `%s` and `str`, the script prints 51 values one by one without a roblem. But if I use `%s` and `str` in `fprintf` it only prints the first line "Turn :  5 6   ", then it prints out strange characters as below.

[image: screen shot of output of fprintf]

If I use `disp`, it works correctly as below.

[image: screen shot of output of disp]

Comment: The conventional solution would be fprintf("Turn : %d %d",[r;t] )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was just reading [this blog post by Loren Shure](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2019/09/09/compose-yourself/) of the MathWorks. It taught me about [`compose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/compose.html). `compose` perfectly solves your problem. Use it instead of `fprintf` to combine your data into strings. Then use `fprintf` to print the strings to screen:

```matlab
s = compose("%s %d %d", str, r.', t.');
fprintf("%s\n", s)
```

`compose` is much more intuitive than `fprintf` in how the values for each `%` element is taken from the input data. It generates one string for each row in the data. `str` is a scalar, its value will be repeated for each row. `r.'` and `t.'` here have the same number of rows, which will also be the number of rows in `s`.

Note: `compose` is new in MATLAB R2016b.

Comment: Can it be regarded as a replacement for sprintf?

Comment: @rahnema1: I don't know if it's a replacement, but it definitely is a better alternative to `sprintf`. :)

Comment: Thanks Cris. Worked like a charm. One more question. Why does .' mean near r and t ?

Comment: @ivbtar: That is the transpose operator. The data needs to be passed as column vectors, so that each row can be one string. You could do `r(:)` as well. (Note that `'` is not the transpose, it's the complex conjugate transpose!)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need any functions. When working with strings, if you use the `+` operator you get the conversion for free:

```
>> str + r + " " + t

ans = 

1×51 string array
Columns 1 through 5
"Turn : 5 85"    "Turn : 6 122"    "Turn : 7 165"    "Turn : 8 215"    "Turn : 9 272"
...
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know it did this. I guess this automatic conversion makes sense, but it still makes my hair stand on end...

Comment: Yeah, I think it's more readable but at the same time `compose` is probably more robust.